# Error with schema on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, database-schema, postgresql-9.0, geonetwork

I have a tomcat 7 server, and a postgreSQL 9.0 DB. I use it to setup a development environment for geonetwork metadata editor. Everything is set up according to the geonetwork web-site tutorial. I have a problem with connecting the server with the DB. I have set up a default schema and all of my settings (I think) are good). Here is the error I am getting:

> Raised exception while starting appl handler. Skipped.
>   Exception  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
>   Message  ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in

Comment: Sounds like this is not a problem with Tomcat, but with your schema setup. Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

One way to can cause this error is to set a bad `search_path`.  Since it creates the table in the first valid schema on your search path, an empty path (or one containing only non-existent schema names or ones in which you don't have create rights) will cause this error.

```
test=# set search_path = some_nonexistent_schema_name;
SET
test=# create table w (id int);
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
```

It would help if you showed both your `search_path` value and the failing statement.